# Joda LocalDate - still an instant?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm looking for a proper serializable date-only class. Got a server in Central time zone, I want users in the Eastern to enter date as 2010-11-23, and users in Pacific to see it as 2010-11-23 (and vice versa).

`java.util.Date` is a time-sensitive instant, so it doesn't work for me. Not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I decided to give Joda Time a try. According to overview, `LocalDate` is a "class representing a local date without a time (no time zone)" - just what I need.

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be time zone independent. In database I have 2010-11-23. On server, I transform it to `LocalDate` with `new LocalDate(java.sql.Date)`. `date.toString()` prints 2010-11-23.

After deserializing that on client, `date.ToString()` prints 2010-11-22 and `date.getDayOfMonth()` is 22. But `date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()` produces 2010-11-23T00:00:00.000-08:00.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a proper date-only time zone insensitive class in Joda?

**EDIT**: In database I am using a timezone insensitive column (`DATE` in Postgres). Server is in the same time zone as the database, so it reads the date just fine. It is not an issue. **I am looking for a Java type that once instantiated in one time zone, has the same civil (partial) date value in all time zones.**

**EDIT 2**: On server everything is loaded properly and has UTC time zone. After investigation I think it is a bug in `ISOChronology`. On client it is unpacked as America/Los_Angeles. The reason is that serialization is done with:

```
class ISOChronology {
// ...
    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new Stub(getZone());
    }

    private static final class Stub implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6212696554273812441L;

        private transient DateTimeZone iZone;

        Stub(DateTimeZone zone) {
            iZone = zone;
        }

        private Object readResolve() {
            return ISOChronology.getInstance(iZone);
        }

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
            out.writeObject(iZone);
        }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            iZone = (DateTimeZone)in.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck serializing with a transient field.

Comment: If you want to ignore timezone, can you just use UTC/GMT in all places?

Comment: Which Joda version are you using and how are the objects serialized? For standard Java serialization, the Stub class has proper writeObject/readObject methods for "manual" handling of the iZone field, but this may of course fail with other serialization implementations like IIOP, SOAP or anything else trying to automatically extract field values from object instances.

Comment: @jarnbjo 1.6.2. Serializer is OK, the issue like I pointed out above is that `Stub.iZone` is transient.

Comment: iZone is transient, but the serialization is implemented in the writeObject/readObject methods where iZone is written/read explicitly.

Comment: @jarnbjo Oh my, that is indeed what's happening. It seems to be one bit of the ugly Java serialization API that my dated Hessian lib doesn't seem to support.

Comment: That's why I asked if you're using standard serialization or any other serialization technology. Hessian is ignoring the transient field, but is also not using the readObject/writeObject methods, so that the time zone is lost and replaced with the default timezone instead of UTC when the object is deserialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `trasient` time zone in the stub class shown above is a bug. Amazing that it wasn't caught in tens of thousands of tests or 5 years of widespread usage. Bug report https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3117678&group_id=97367&atid=617889

The timezone should be UTC, as defined in the Javadoc - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html . Deserializing to get any other time zone will break the internal state of the class.

JSR-310 uses a much better internal design which doesn't suffer from this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Do I understand correctly that you're saying it should always be UTC in order to make it absolutely timezone insensitive?

Comment: Internally, once construction has completed, the time zone in the chronology must be UTC, or the class invariants fail.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that using `new LocalDate(java.sql.Date)` constructor may be the culprit.

Instead, try using `new LocalDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`.

See `LocalDate` [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) and [manual](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_partial.html) for more details.

Comment: in that case, new LocalDate(date.getTime()) should work.  The constructor LocalDate(Object) notes it tries to take the timezone if it can be obtained.

Comment: I'll give all these options a shot. If it worked, though, it would mean `LocalDate` still is timezone-sensitive and I need to be extremely careful with it. That's what I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to check what is *actually* in your database. If it really is using absolute timestamps and they're all in one timezone, then you've got parse the values in *that* timezone and only then convert to a LocalDate. If you've got a string in your database, then parse that string and use the constructor for LocalDate that takes the information that you've really got. Whatever you do, don't get into mixing up between instants and dates; as you've found from your problems, they're not interchangeable.